# Flutter Custom fonts not wrking in Material App ThemeData

Tags: flutter, fonts, flutter-web

recently i develop a new project in flutter web i face to serious problem in flutter custom fonts, I fallow flutter documentation  how to use custom fonts in flutter app every things work properly , but my problem is that when I want to set default font family to my chosen custom font family  in flutter material app like this: `theme: ThemeData(fontFamily:'ComforterBrush-Regular'),` it not working but when I use this font family in text widget like this  `Text( text, style: TextStyle( color: kPrimaryColor, fontSize: size, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'ComforterBrush-Regular'), );`
it work but it make me crazy I should use every time custom fonts family for every text widget.  I want automatically every text widget gave font family from material app. please guide me!!!!

my complete code:

```
enter code hMaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'ComforterBrush-Regular'),
        scrollBehavior: CustomAppScrollBehavior(),
        title: 'Maliha Arash',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        darkTheme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            platform: TargetPlatform.android,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
            canvasColor: hBackgroudColor,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme()),
        home: CustomPageView(),
      );
```

my pubspec.yaml file
[image]

my FontManifest.json file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To enable font by default for all widgets you need to do:

1. Add font family to project(seems it's done)
2. Add to pubspec like that(**please compare your and mine, here is differences**):

```dart
flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
      fonts:
        - family: Silkscreen
          fonts:
            - asset: assets/Silkscreen-Regular.ttf
            - asset: assets/Silkscreen-Bold.ttf
              style: 700
```

3. Add to a material app like that(**difference here as well**)

```dart
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              theme: ThemeData(
                fontFamily: 'Silkscreen',
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              ),
              home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
            );
          }
```

Your problem seems with name, font family should be called `ComforterBrush` in `pubspec` and in `MaterialApp`, application simply cannot find right file

For web you don't need font manifest. Everything should run out of the box.